# Taking char and int inputs

Tags: java, input, char, int

I am currently working on a Knight's tour implementation in Java. I am trying to take the user input in the form (file)(rank) on my board.

File would be a char (a, b, c or d) and rank an int (1, 2 or 3).

I know how to get the input of these individually but how would I combine the input of the two, so that for example 'd2' is valid.

I am a beginner to java so any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: `String st = ch+""+in;`

Comment: Thanks a lot, this helped with exactly what I needed!

Answer (score 1):

You can do this:

```
String st = ch+""+in;
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use String format like this:

```
String input = String.format("%s"+"%d", file, rank);
```

where `file` is your `char` input and `rank` is your `int` input